# How to run writable containers in Snakemake?

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I am trying to use a QIIME2 plugin inside a container with the `--use-singularity` option and I keep getting this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` because aparently QIIME2 needs to update some internal files during execution. I am aware that singularity by default runs read-only containers, so I am adding the option `--singularity-args "\\-\\-writable-tmpfs"` to try to make the containers writable, but still get the same error. Is there anything else I should do to run writable containers in Snakemake rules? I could not find anything in the documentation or previous questions/issues.

Edit: I also get these warnings from matplotlib `Matplotlib created a temporary config/cache directory at /tmp/matplotlib-d90_a5d2 because the default path (/home/qiime2/matplotlib) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and to better support multiprocessing.`

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a way to run writable containers, but my problem was solved by adding `qiime dev refresh-cache` in my dockerfile. This forced qiime2 to update its files during container creation, solving my issue.

Comment: How long did this take for you? I'm running this and it's been on this stage for over 4 hours.

Comment: It only takes a few seconds to create the cache

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with Docker on Apple Silicon.  I've had some other issues not related to this.